# bash print whole line after splitting line with ifs

Tags: bash, delimiter

When `awk` splits a line into fields using a delimiter, it maintains the original line in the `$0` variable.  Thus it can print the original line (assuming nothing else modifies `$0`) after performing operations on the individual fields.  Can bash's `read` do something similar, where it has not only the individual elements but also the entire line?

E.g., with the following `input.txt`

```
foo,bar
baz,quz
```

The `awk` behavior that i'm trying to imitate in bash is:
`awk -F, '($1 == "baz") {print $0}' input.txt`

This will print `baz,quz` because `$0` is the whole line that was read, even though the line was also split into two fields (`$1` and `$2`).

**Bash:**

```
while IFS=, read -r first second; do
   if [[ "$first" == lemur ]]; then
      # echo the entire line
   fi
done < input.txt
```

In this simple case it wouldn't be too difficult to recreate the original line by echoing the `$first` and `$second` variables with a comma between them.  But in more complex scenarios where `IFS` may be more than one character and there may be many fields, it becomes much harder to accurately recreate the original line unless *bash* is maintaining it during the read operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you'll have to do it with 2 different `read`s like

```
while read -r line; do
    IFS=, read first second <<<"$line"

    if [[ $first == lemur ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    fi
done < input.txt
```