# Replacing value inside while loop with using sed and IFS

Tags: linux, bash

Im using a while loop to split the line into variables and use those same variable inside the loop to pass into sed to replace in the line. Is there a way to achieve printing the whole line without having to print out all the while variables into a new file?

```
while IFS=';' read -r task_id date name action; do
    sed -e "s/\$date/$date/; s/\$name/$name/" >> $TASKSFILE.tmp
done < $FILE
```

Input file would look like:

```
1;20190423;Name1;print $date $name
2;20190424;Name2;print $date $name
```

Expected output:

```
1;20190423;Name1;print 20190423 Name1
2;20190424;Name2;print 20190424 Name2
```

Comment: Just `+1` for not considering using `eval` for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash print whole line after splitting line with ifs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503935/bash-print-whole-line-after-splitting-line-with-ifs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use awk for this? It's available on all POSIX-compliant platforms.

```
awk -F';' '{sub(/\$date/,$2);sub(/\$name/,$3)} 1' "$FILE" > "${TASKSFILE}.tmp"
```

```
$ awk -F';' '{sub(/\$date/,$2);sub(/\$name/,$3)} 1' file
1;20190423;Name1;print 20190423 Name1
2;20190424;Name2;print 20190424 Name2
```